# Applying Jquery Accordion on a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to apply jquery accordion function to a div with a particular class... i.e. div id='abc'we use $("#abc").accordion(); but how to accomplish if we have div class='abc'??

Comment: sounds like you need to learn the basics of jQuery, or even better, javascript :)

Comment: @red-X That's more likely to be a thing of CSS

Comment: @Sam, could be but I would think someone would consider learning how to select id's and classes in css before even thinking about javascript... that may be a bit naive though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JQuery class selectors](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to select the elements with the class.
Example -

```
$("div.someclass").accordion();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LY2gY/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".className").accordion();
```

See [Class Selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)